# A user suggested an edit for my question. People rejected it. Is there a way to thank the user and tell these people that they are wrong

Tags: feature-request

Today I got a notification that someone suggested an edit to my question. When I opened it, [it turned out that 3 people already rejected the edit, and 2 accepted it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6682810), which lead to ultimately rejecting it.

I would like to merge it, but it is impossible.

The edit is 100% correct and I updated the answer manually(SO doesn't allow any other way) and people who rejected the answer clearly have no idea who Herb Sutter is and shouldn't have been accepting/rejecting this edit in the first place.

Why is there no discussion of the edit? I would like to have one. It would be nice if I could send a message like "hey, [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088577/michał-góral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088577/micha%C5%82-g%C3%B3ral) , thank you for your edit. People rejecting good edit -- you're wrong, learn who Herb Sutter is".

Comment: Too much drama ...

Comment: How exactly should the reviewers know the edit is correct or incorrect? All they see is somebody replacing a link with a totally different link, which of course should be rejected. The correct way to go about this would be if the user had posted a comment telling you "Hey, I think your first link is incorrect, you probably wanted to link to [...]".

Comment: You can *trivially* copy the link across to your post yourself. It is right there in the suggested edit.

Comment: I trivially copied the link as I mentioned in the original post, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: The reviewers were right to reject the edit, so there's no need to tell them they're wrong. The suggested edit replaced one link with another without a clear explanation, which should always be rejected.

Comment: The four letters that form GOTW and the name "Herb Sutter", while familiar to you and me, might not be familiar to others. As one of the reviewers said,  it seems that the editor *"has replaced the link to a university's PDf with one to a private (his?) blog"* ... it happens. And even though I wouldn't classify this as a mistake, mistakes happen as well. If they don't happen all the time in a far too significant number, then nothing really needs to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is there no discussion of the edit?

Because it would take far too long and basically would result in more discussion and complaining without actually resolving anything.

Users are not selected for reviewing specific edits for a post based on their experience, programming language skills, or qualifications.  The only qualifications are they earn 2000 rep on the site and maintain a positive review history (as judged by audits and occasionally moderators).

Anything more than that would unnecessarily complicate the edit process and make it more difficult for users to edit posts.

This is why the suggest edit process has very simple rules

1. Does the edit improve the post or make the post easier to read?
2. Does the edit not conflict with the original author's intent

If the user can say Yes to both points (or at least not say no), then the edit is probably of good enough quality to approve.

Both points come into play for this specific edit.

- Changing the link does not necessarily improve the post.  Maybe it does, maybe it doesn't.  As you mention, the reviewers may not have known who **Herb Sutter** is and why this link improves the post.  So they rejected it, and I would have too.  If the editor has left a better edit description explaining **why** this link is better than the one you originally had, then I may have considered approved it (although I probably would have skipped it since I don't know who Herb Sutter is).
- Changing a link that you provided for reference clearly conflicts with what appears to be your intent.  Just because you like the link better doesn't mean that the editor was correct, it just means he guessed that you would think the reference was better.

The more appropriate action for this user would have been to leave a comment suggesting you edit the better link into the post.

There is an old feature request on Meta.StackExchange asking to give the ability for the post owner to retroactively approve a rejected edit ([Allow the owner of a post to approve a suggested edit even if it was rejected by reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by)).  You may be interested in reading it as the pros and cons of that idea are discussed.

Comment: *"clearly conflicts with what appears to be your intent"* ... from the perspective of the reviewers, absolutely. But based on the text which refers to "GOTW 88", the intent of the OP and the mistake made are clear. The suggested edit was valid but - perhaps surprisingly - the subsequent rejections can't be classified as invalid either. It's one of those outliers I guess. :)

Comment: "Just because you like the link better doesn't mean that the editor was correct, it just means he guessed that you would think the reference was better." -- It not just a _better_ link, it is the _correct_ link, the previous link was _wrong_. I accidentally linked to the wrong thing(to the pdf which I also mentioned in the same post). I think you and other commenters made a good point about providing proper description/context for the edit, so I'm going to accept this answer

Comment: @Bart yup, that's why I added the *"appears"* in there.

Comment: @AlexanderPutilin but that's the point - the users have no way to know they are wrong given the current review process.  Absent better info, the reviewers have to assume your links were right and someone changing it was not.  It is unfortunate but if the reviewer stopped to actually check the links to see, they probably would have lost their place in line to review and someone else would have swooped in.

Comment: "... if the reviewer stopped to actually check the links to see, they probably would have lost their place in line to review ..." - Can't they open another browser tab or window to do the research, and leave the review page open?

Comment: @KevinFegan at the time I wrote that comment, suggested edit reviews were close to a free for all.  You could potentially have multiple people shown the same review and the first 5 reviews completed were the recorded votes.  Since then, a feature was added to briefly limit the number of reviewers shown a specific suggested edit to assure them time to review.

Comment: Great, thanks, glad to hear it has been changed.